# Javascript to run on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having some issues getting some javascript code to run whenever a form is submitted.

Here is my code

```
   <form onsubmit="return header_search()" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Tack" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
   </form>

   <script>
       function header_search() {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("submitted");
       } 
   </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgwzn/

Answer (score 2):

[As @Quentin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20182796/30433), it's not behaving as expected because you are not defining `e` anywhere.

As you tagged jQuery, I'll suggest an alternative using it. Add an ID to your form and then define your `onsubmit` behavior in JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<form id="your-form" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    ...
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#your-form').submit(function(e) {
    alert('submitted');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I think this would be the easier solution as you would not have to deal with browser compatibility issues (hey IE, I'm looking at you) with the `event` variable and `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`. jQuery takes care of that for you.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MGA74/

Answer (score 1):

You never define `e`, so `e.preventDefault();` throws an exception and the script stops.

You can either remove `e.preventDefault();` or move to a modern event binding style:

Stop using intrinsic event attributes, bind your event handler with JS and make sure you accept an argument for the event object.

```
function header_search(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("submitted");
} 
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', header_search);
```

Reading the documentation ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a good place to look) on browser support for and alternatives to `querySelector` and `addEventListener` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to cancel the submittion just user `return false;` in your code or use `return false;` in the onsubmit

like below

```
   <script>
       function header_search() {
          alert("submitted");
          return false;
       } 
   </script>
```

or

```
<form onsubmit="header_search(); return false;"...
```

Edit: e.preventDefault(); is  not needed. also return is not needed in the form tag.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` both prevent the default event (which is to submit the form and load the action page). In OPs trivial implementation it's not needed per see but I do think it's likely (s)he'll need it.